# SELECT data from another table with max date

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2014, maxdate

I need help with a SELECT query in which I need to join to another table and get record with max date. I have created sample to demonstrate. My last SELECT is incorrect and I need guidance to fix it or if there is a better way in Sql server 2014

```
CREATE TABLE #EmpTable
(
    EmpNum INT,
    colA VARCHAR(5) NULL,
    colB VARCHAR(5) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE #EmpDetailTbl
(
    EmpNum INT,
    Name VARCHAR(10),
    Department VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    ReportDate DATETIME NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #EmpTable 
VALUES (101, 'val11', 'Val21'), (102, 'val12', 'Val21'), (103, 'val13', 'Val23');

INSERT INTO #EmpDetailTbl 
VALUES (101, 'emp101', 'Dept1', '05/01/2018'), (101, 'emp101', 'Dept2', '06/01/2018'),
       (101, 'emp101', 'Dept1', '05/01/2017'), (102, 'emp102', 'Dept3', '04/01/2018'),
       (102, 'emp102', 'Dept1', '05/01/2018')

--select * from  #EmpDetailTbl
--select * from  #EmpTable

SELECT 
    a.EmpNum, Name, ColA, ColB, Department
FROM 
    #EmpTable a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    #EmpDetailTbl b ON a.EmpNum = b.EmpNum 
                    AND ReportDate = (SELECT MAX(ReportDate) 
                                      FROM #EmpDetailTbl 
                                      a.EmpNum = b.EmpNum)
```

Comment: Desired output?

Comment: one rec per EmpNum with max(ReportDate)

Answer (score 2):

Use `rank()` analytic function to enumerate rows based on their report dates and then pick only the first for each employee:

```
SELECT EmpNum, Name, ColA, ColB, Department
FROM (
  SELECT 
    a.EmpNum, b.Name, a.ColA, a.ColB, b.Department,
    rank() over (partition by a.EmpNum order by b.ReportDate desc) as rn
  FROM #EmpTable a
  LEFT JOIN #EmpDetailTbl b ON 
    a.EmpNum = b.EmpNum
  ) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This query will take care of ties: in case there is more than 1 record for employee with the same date which also happens to be maximum it will show them all.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you can try this to get MaxDate row.

using a `exists` to get `MAX(b1.ReportDate)` by `EmpNum`

```
select a.EmpNum, Name, ColA, ColB, Department
FROM #EmpTable a
LEFT JOIN #EmpDetailTbl b on a.EmpNum = b.EmpNum 
WHERE exists (
    SELECT 1
    FROM #EmpDetailTbl b1
    WHERE b1.EmpNum = b.EmpNum
    GROUP BY b1.EmpNum
    HAVING MAX(b1.ReportDate) = b.ReportDate
)
```

sqlfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a3deade95dbd25d9cadadee37e16d9c6

**Result**

```
EmpNum  Name    ColA    ColB    Department
101    emp101   val11   Val21   Dept2
102    emp102   val12   Val21   Dept1
103    emp103   val13   Val23   Dept1
```

Comment: The sample works as expected, however, in my real query I am not getting all the rows from #EmpTable even though using LEFT JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN. Can you think of a reason?

Comment: It should be getting all rows from ` #EmpTable` because `LEFT JOIN`, if not could you provide some data and now result set and your expected result?  @SilverFish

Comment: I think it is due to the WHERE clause in the inner SQL which acts as INNER JOIN. I tried replacing with Right Join but still inconsistent result. I will try to create test data to mimic the issue

Comment: Please see updated example. I removed emp103 from #EmpDetailTbl to demonstrate left join not working. Now it will return only EmpNum 101, 102 but not 103 eventhough using left join

Comment: From your expect result you need to use `UNION ALL` to combine Maxdate result and No associated EMPID result set   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d4795ea26d3463160e8ec34cccc45937 @SilverFish

Comment: @SilverFish You can mark this answer if that help you :)

Answer (score 0):

ReportDate  SHOULD BE a.ReportDate

Comment: a has no column as ReportDate

Comment: Ya but b has report date then write b.reportdate.My point is  give  table alias to the correspondig column